# How to add image field in dynamic input group for magento admin configuration setting?

Tags: image, magento, dynamic, configuration, field

I have created a module which add dynamic input group to magento admin configuration.

I have added image field but it can't save in database. Means if I select image than only image store in database in core_config_data — the encrypted value of row (just image field value)

If I remove image field than the data saved properly in database along with other inputs.

So here I can't save image type data with other data of dynamic input.

Answer (score 0):

I've found reason + solution, maybe this is helpful for someone. Magento is using the wrong backend model. For saving images the backend model must be *system_config_backend_image*. But as you've added the fields dynamically (and not inside the system.xml) the fields have no assigned backend model, so magento will use the default for text values etc..

The solution is, to use the clone_fields functionality. Please find my explanation how to use it on my blog post http://www.mellority-report.com/magento-dynamic-config-fields-with-custom-backend-models/

Comment: The link is broken. Please post your solution here.